# Solr performance: multiValued filed vs separate fields

Tags: performance, solr

I wonder about performance difference of 2 indexing options:
1-  multivalued field
2-  separate fields

The case is as follows:
Each document has 100 “properties”: prop1..prop100. 
The values are strings and there is no relation between different properties.
I would like to search by exact match on several properties by known values (like ids).
For example: search for all docs having prop1=”blue” and prop6=”high”

I can choose to build the indexes in 1 of 2 ways:
1-  the trivial way – 100 separate fields, 1 for each property, multiValued=false. the values are just property values.
2-  1 field (named “properties”) multiValued=true. The field will have 100 values: value1=”prop1:blue”.. value6=”high” etc

Is it correct to say that option1 will have much better performance in searching?
How about saving performance?

thanx,
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about performance at this point.  Worry about getting your application correct.  Solr is plenty fast.  Do it right and make each property its own field in Solr.

Comment: Thanx for the response! The thing is that we have current situation of using single multiValued field, and changing it will take lots of work (it's in production already). so, I would like to know if it's worth it from performance perspective.

Comment: Are you having performance problems?  It might be better to post a new question about the performance problems and ask in general how things might be improved, rather than asking "Is this one idea I have to improve performance a good way to do it?"